# Combining multiple survey datasets with design weights in a single model

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, survey, survey-sampling, survey-weights

The analysis of survey data with design weights is a difficult topic. In my case, I am working with two datasets: 1) NHANES data, which makes use of cluster sampling and stratification, and 2) Survey data collected on the same variables in a different population, where data were collected using random sampling and no cluster sampling and stratification.

My goal is to compare the mean value of my response variable, 'DR1TKCAL', between these populations, while controlling for the effects of age and sex (data available in both populations).

If NHANES data were collected using a random sample, then a normal linear model in R on a combined dataset would suffice by estimating the effect of 'population' in the following model:

```
lm(DR1TKCAL ~ population + sex + age, data = combined.data)
```

Due to the complex survey design of NHANES, however, this approach would not produce "correct" standard errors. If I want to account for the survey design of the NHANES data, I can use the survey package and produce proper estimates of the mean and SE of my response variable (DR1TKCAL) for the NHANES sample:

```
diet_design <- svydesign(id = ~ SDMVPSU, strata = ~ SDMVSTRA, nest = TRUE, weight = ~ WTDRD1, data = diet_data)

svyby(~DR1TKCAL, ~sex, diet_design, svymean, na.rm=TRUE, keep.names=FALSE)
```

This would allow me to calculate an unbiased mean and confidence interval for the NHANES data that could be generally compared to my other population, but does not allow formal comparison. Similarly I could use the svyglm() function to estimate the effect of covariates on my response variable for the NHANES data.

So I am wondering if there is a sensible way to combine data across populations to run a single model that properly incorporates the design weights for the NHANES sample while allowing for a formal test of the population means. In other words, how might data with different survey structures be combined for a simple analysis?

This thread contains some discussion of how to combine survey data, but in the context of data collected on the same population over time: [How to combine data from 5 surveys from the same population spanning 10 years](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72094/how-to-combine-data-from-5-surveys-from-the-same-population-spanning-10-years)

My situation is made even more complicated by the need to accommodate multilevel structure in my data, but my searches here and elsewhere turn up many inconclusive threads on how to do this in R, with a possible exception of running models in Stan.

Comment: not sure if http://asdfree.com/statistically-significant-trends-with-multiple-years-of-complex-survey-data.html  is helpful

Comment: That link presents an interesting case, but is not comparable because it the across year comparison can make the use of design weights that are on the same scale. Thanks for the suggestion though!